# Settings to connect a OneLogin PHP SAML Toolkit demo app to an ADFS Identity Provider

Tags: php, saml, adfs, onelogin

I have successfully set up the demo test for the OneLogin PHP SAML Toolkit (https://packagist.org/packages/onelogin/php-saml) connecting to a SAML IdP on onelogin.com following the excellent tutorial here: https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php

Now I am attempting to repoint the demo test to a functioning ADFS IdP we have set up.

Although I understand it is supported, there is no documentation on how to configure the settings.php file.  The SAML 2.0 endpoint URL naming conventions do not seem to map well to ADFS endpoint names or descriptions.

I'm new at SAML and ADFS implementations and would kindly appreciate a pointer to documentation, or ideally, an example settings.php file for a OneLogin PHP SAML Toolkit demo app that points to an ADFS implementation.

Comment: Check http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Password_Management/Configuring_SSO_With_Active_Directorys_ADFS/

Comment: Thank you @smartin!  I found a similar article and solved it.  Am currently putting together an answer on those steps, and a few others, to help someone else.

Comment: @Loren would you mind posting the steps? I am having small difficulties switching over from simpleSAMLphp to OneLogin PHP SAML Toolkit

Comment: @Loren can you post that article or steps? It would be helpful.

Comment: @Rahul_Dange, regrettably, I never completed documenting the steps.  I moved on from that project and no longer have access to the systems.  Please accept my apologies.